# ServiceLoader do not work in packaged Spring Boot apps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

(copy from my GitHub issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22955)

I noticed that Java's ServiceLoader mechanism doesn't work in packaged Spring Boot apps.

### Background

I've tried to use `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager` which relies on `ServiceLoader`s. I was able to successfully launch the app from the IDE but not from the command line.

### Repro

```
// build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release.set(11) // required Gradle >= 6.6
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.python:jython-slim:2.7.2'
}
```

```java
// Main.java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import java.util.Objects;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        var engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python");
        Objects.requireNonNull(engine);
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

It is possible to launch this from the IDE (IntelliJ in my case) but not via the command line:

```sh
gradle bootJar && java -jar build/libs/XXX.jar
```

### Temporary workaround

Instead of using the `ScriptEngineManager` it is possible to directly use Jython's `ScriptEngine` implementation:

```java
  var engine = new org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
```

Comment: I don't know for Gradle, and I don't have source code for the maven based project where I had similar problem at work, but I think you should look for something called "layout" in the gradle plugin: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/0.0.x/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-configuration-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ServiceLoader` mechanism is correctly finding `PyScriptEngineFactory`. The problem is then a silent failure when it attempts to create a script engine from it. Unfortunately, when you call `getEngineByName(String)`, `ScriptEngineManager` swallows any exception thrown by `getScriptEngine()`:

```
try {
    ScriptEngine engine = spi.getScriptEngine();
    engine.setBindings(getBindings(), ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
    return engine;
} catch (Exception exp) {
    if (DEBUG) exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Your work around doesn't work for me, but that's useful as it allows me to see the exception swallowed by `ScriptEngineManager`. It is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
    at org.python.core.PrePy.getJarFileNameFromURL(PrePy.java:427)
    at org.python.core.PrePy._getJarFileName(PrePy.java:362)
    at org.python.core.PrePy.getJarFileName(PrePy.java:345)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.doInitialize(PySystemState.java:1195)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1130)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1085)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1080)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1075)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.initialize(PySystemState.java:1070)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.<init>(PySystemState.java:207)
    at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.threadLocalStateInterpreter(PythonInterpreter.java:80)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.<init>(PyScriptEngine.java:27)
    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngineFactory.getScriptEngine(PyScriptEngineFactory.java:85)
    at com.example.demo.Gh22955Application.main(Gh22955Application.java:11)
    ... 8 more
```

`PrePy` is making some assumptions about `jar:file:` URLs that don't hold true in a Spring Boot fat jar. Spring Boot provides an escape hatch for this, allowing a jar file to be automatically unpacked from the fat jar when it's launched. In this case, it's the `jython-slim` jar that needs to be unpacked. To do that, add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
bootJar {
    requiresUnpack "**/jython-slim*"
}
```